# geom_density() grouped plot with discrete x axis is not smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2, kernel-density, density-plot

I was working with a dataset that consists of two different groups of observations where the value is an integer.  I wanted to plot the density of these to get a sense for how the different groups are distributed over the values.

What happened was one group had a 'smooth' density while the other had a 'wavy' density.  I know this has something to do with bandwidth and the fact that my data is basically tied to discrete observations but I would love if someone can explain exactly why.

Here's an example:

```
data2 <- rbind(
    data.frame(group=rep('poisson1', 1000), value = rpois(1000, 5)),
    data.frame(group=rep('poisson2', 1000), value = rpois(1000, 45)))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data2, aes(x=value, fill=group)) +
  geom_density()
```

[image]

And strangely, I can create that dataframe again to get a new sample, and the plot sometimes is smooth:
[image]

Comment: Look at the docs for `geom_density`. There are a number of arguments that get passed to the underlying `density` function, including the kernel type and bandwidth

Comment: Yes, I did read the docs for geom_density, which lead me to stats::density, and I'm sure it's related to the fact that the x values are discrete and the chosen bandwidth.  But I'm still not entirely clear on why, especially when I can see the same thing with a plot of a single sample of 1000 draws from rpois with lambda = 5.  Most of the time the density plot is smooth, but every once in a while it's not.  I'm hoping someone can explain why in a way I can understand.

Answer (score 3):

Observed smoothness (or lack of smoothness) is "caused" by `rpois()` function. `lambda` argument in `rpois()` function has to be *non-negative mean* of wanted random distribution. Therefore, when you pass `lambda` that is closer to zero (`rpois(1000, 5)`) it will generate less unique values (as it's bounded by zero).

Consider this example:

```
nValue <- 1e3
nLambda <- c(1:9, seq(10, 100, 10))

foo <- lapply(nLambda, function(lambda) {
    data.frame(value = rpois(nValue, lambda), lambda)
})
data <- do.call(rbind, foo)
ggplot(data, aes(value, group = lambda, color = lambda)) +
    geom_density()
```

[image]

We can see that `lambda` closer to zero will have peaks, while moving away from zero will generate more smooth lines.

You can also test this by looking into variance in each `lambda` group:

```
ggplot(aggregate(data$value, list(data$lambda), var), aes(Group.1, x)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point() +
    labs(x = "Lambda",
         y = "Variance")
```

[image]

Comment: That makes some sense, but I can plot a sample of 1000 draws from a single rpois with lambda = 5 several times, and most of the time the density plot is smooth.  Every once in a while I'll see one thats 'wavy.'  I guess this is just surprising to me.

Comment: @JasonAment it's just a probability: if you sample 5 numbers with mean 5, then you can get `3,4,5,6,7` (smooth) or `5,5,5,5,5` (one peak).

Comment: I understand there will be variation in a sample, but I'm still surprised that repeatedly sampling from rpois with n = 1000 and plotting the density of that sample usually produces a 'smooth', but always slightly varying density plot, but every once in a while produces a 'wavy' one.  Beyond simple sampling variability, is there something special about how the bandwidth is being chosen and the fact that the x values are discrete that would explain this?

Comment: I doubt that it has something to do with bandwidth, if you would look at raw values in R you should observed some kind of low-uniqueness pattern